# ASP.NET - Grid View and List View with Paging

Tags: asp.net, list, view, grid

We are working on Grid View and List View controls in an ASP.NET application.  To provide better performance we planned to provide pagination with 10 records display, at a time. We does not want to get all the records from database (at a time) and bind them to these controls i.e. we need to get only 10 records at a time from database and bind them but we need to implement pagination.

Kindly let me know if you know any code samples to achieve this functionality.

Thank you.
Shravya.

Answer (score 2):

**[Paging in a GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx)**

**[Walkthrough: Displaying, Paging, and Sorting Data Using the ListView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515102.aspx)**

Comment: Links without explanation don't usually help that much, for instance in this case you linked 2 MSDN articles that may be helpful to the OP but do not distill to an answer to his question or even a point in the right direction.